# Is there any better way to upsert on CosmosDB by not id?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a client app where I create models and store locally and also send a mapped DTO to web api.

```
class TestModel // Locally stored model
    {
       Guid OwnerId;
       Guid LocalId;
       string Name;
    }

class TestDto // Remotely stored model 
    {
       Guid Id;
       Guid OwnerId;
       Guid LocalId;
       string Name;
    }
```

---

On Server Side:
When I send a mapped DTO to the Web Api I would like to update but because the model is not aware the Id of the database stored DTO I use OwnerId & LocalId to detect the stored DTO to update.

```
   public async Task<TestDto?> UpdateAsync(TestDto testDto)
   {
       IOrderedQueryable<TestDto> queryable = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<TestDto>();

       // Construct LINQ query
       var matches = queryable.Where(p => p.LocalId == testDto.LocalId && p.OwnerId == testDto.OwnerId);

       using FeedIterator<TestDto> linqFeed = matches.ToFeedIterator();

       List<TestDto> results = new List<TestDto>();
       while (linqFeed.HasMoreResults)
       {
           var response = await linqFeed.ReadNextAsync();
           results.AddRange((IEnumerable<TestDto>)response);
       }

       var result = results.SingleOrDefault();

       if (result != null && results.Count == 1)
       {
           testDto.Id = result.Id; // need set to update
           await _container.UpsertItemAsync<TestDto>(testDto, new PartitionKey(testDto.OwnerId.ToString()));
       }

       return result;
   }
```

Is there any better way to filter out? To select the updatable document? Instead of linqFeed and singleOrDefault?

Comment: What is the logic behind the `id` generation? And which is the Partition Key Definition of the Container?

Comment: I use OwnerId as  Partition Key, do you mean I would not even need the Id on TestDto?

Comment: The reason I ask is, if you know the `id` and Partition Key Value of a document, instead of a query, you can do `ReadItemAsync(id value, new PartitionKey(pk value)` and it's cheaper RU wise and faster than a query

Comment: In essence, this app operates on the Maui platform, and my preference is to function without an internet connection. However, if internet access is available, I'd like to synchronize data online for backup purposes. When making API calls, I lack the ID because of the model-to-dto mapping. The local db has models as TestModel. Whenever I add, update, or delete a model, it's essential to sync these changes with the remote database. In such instances, I rely on the local ID and OwnerID to locate the specific item.

Comment: * So technically If i do an upsert I  would need to find the item by localId and OwnerId and I can get the remote id as well. Actually I am wondering if I would need an Id at all on the remote database.

Comment: Cosmos DB has no `id` generation on the database, so it's your application defining which is the `id` on creation. That is why I asked, how is your `id` defined in the code whenever you do original/first creation. If you know it before-hand (for example, upon creation, the `id` equals to some generated string that uses some value from the DTO, then you can use that logic and perform a ReadItem

Comment: I have the following Add method on the Web Api side:

`public async Task<TestDto> Add(TestDto testDto)
    {
        testDto.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        return await _container.CreateItemAsync(testDto, new PartitionKey(testDto.OwnerId.ToString()));
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks mostly fine. You can improve performance by only selecting the `Id` property and instead of returning all results only return the first result. Even if you expect only a single result the query will always scan all items instead of returning once it finds any item.

You will need to retrieve the `Id` some way so unless you have the `Id` readily available you'll always have a query run somewhere. There's not much else to improve apart from maybe cleaning up the code a bit for readability.

```cs
using var iterator = container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<TestDto>()
    .Where(p => p.LocalId == testDto.LocalId && p.OwnerId == testDto.OwnerId)
    .Take(1)
    .Select(p => p.Id)
    .ToFeedIterator();

Guid Id;
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var feed = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    Id = feed.FirstOrDefault();
}
```